# concatenate splatted lists

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out how I can code a function that will concatenate any number of lists that uses a splat.

the code below is the closest that I've gotten to where I want to be, but I'm trying to get the function to output a list that looks like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But I only end having it show up as three nested lists.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
m = [1, 2, 3]
n = [4, 5, 6]
o = [7, 8, 9]

# Update the below function to take
# an arbitrary number of arguments
def join_lists(*args):
    return args


print join_lists(m, n, o)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are limited to only "basic" functions (as disclosed in a recent comment), here's a short list comprehension:

```
def join_lists(*args):
    return [i for L in args for i in L]
```

or, unrolled as nested loops (exactly equivalent):

```
def join_lists(*args):
    out = []
    for L in args:
        for i in L:
            out.append(i)
    return out
```

Answer (score 8):

`itertools` to the rescue!

```
def join_lists(*args):
    return list(itertools.chain(*args))
```

Comment: after walking away from the problem for a few days, I came up with this function and was wondering why I get an error message saying "can only concatenate list(not tuple) to list.  Thank you!

    m = [1, 2, 3]
    n = [4, 5, 6]
    o = [7, 8, 9]

    # Update the below function to take
    # an arbitrary number of arguments
    def join_lists(*args):
        masterList=[]
        i=0
        while i<=len(args):
            masterList=masterList+args
            i+=1


    print join_lists(m, n, o)

also, I seem to have issues w/mini markdown code formatting even w/indentations

Comment: You need to do `masterList = masterList + args[i]`. But, I'd suggest using `masterList.extend(args[i])`.

Answer (score 2):

In the unlikely event that you want to code that by hand :)

```
>>> def joinlists(*args):
...     l = []
...     for arg in args:
...             l.extend(arg)
...     return l
... 
>>> joinlists(m, n, o)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or this :-

```
>>> def joinlists(*args):
...     l = []
...     for arg in args:
...         for item in arg:
...             l.append(item)
...     return l
... 
>>> joinlists(m, n, o)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! Just for the heck of it, I was hoping to limit myself to the functions that have been covered by codecademy up to this lesson and unfortunately, this would exclude both extend() and itertools.  Given the nature of the lesson, I'm not sure how I can communicate what is allowed and what isn't.  The best I can say is that this is a very introductory part of the python course on codecademy.  <br/>For your reference, the lesson can be found [here](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-nzzVa/4/2?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096)

Comment: Yeah, that's somewhat limiting.  On the other hand, since Codeacademy is essentially built around self-study, I would suggest that exploring the Python documentation to find ways to accomplish what's asked of you beyond what's presented in the lessons will make you a much stronger and more capable Python programmer in the long run.  Spending some time going through the documentation for built-in types to see what's possible would find you solutions like `list.extend()` and exploring a little farther would help you find `itertools`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, args)`:

```
>>> m = [1, 2, 3]
>>> n = [4, 5, 6]
>>> o = [7, 8, 9]
>>>
>>> def join_lists(*args):
...     return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, args)
...
>>> join_lists(m,n,o)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

or `reduce(operator.add, args)`:

```
>>> import operator
>>>
>>> m = [1, 2, 3]
>>> n = [4, 5, 6]
>>> o = [7, 8, 9]
>>>
>>> def join_lists(*args):
...     return reduce(operator.add, args)
...
>>> print join_lists(m,n,o)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```